# sql statement update multiple values in multiple rows in complex where statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume i have 6 columns named a,b,c,d,e,f in a table X

my logic is this:

```
if a=0 and b-0 and c=0 then d=0 e=0 f=0
if a=0 and b-0 and c=1 then d=0 e=0 f=1
if a=0 and b-0 and c=2 then d=0 e=0 f=8
if a=1 and b-0 and c=2 then d=0 e=555 f=8
```

etc

how do i build it in one single query statement

the DB is postgresql

I need to update like that around 10K records

Comment: `CASE` and `SWITCH` I'd think

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? what's your dbms?

Comment: Why do you need a single statement? that would be quite easy if you simply used four `UPDATE` statements. One for each condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I took the "etc" after those 4 statements to mean there were many more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
update x
  set d = t.d, 
      e = t.e,
      f = t.f
from (
  values 
    (0,0,0,0,0,0),
    (0,0,1,0,0,1),
    (0,0,2,0,0,8),
    (1,0,2,0,555,8)
) as t(a,b,c,d,e,f)
where x.a = t.a
  and x.b = t.b
  and x.c = t.c
;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/APBVYG17890

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I recommend a completely different approach. If you created a table that allowed you to crosswalk the values, it would be re-usable, concise, and easy to maintain.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
        a INT
    ,   b INT
    ,   c INT
    ,   d INT
    ,   e INT
    ,   f INT
)

INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (0,0,0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (0,0,1,0,0,1);
INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (0,0,2,0,0,8);
INSERT INTO t (a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (1,0,2,0,555,8);

SELECT * FROM t
```

You can simply join to this table on those three values and get the value you want to for d, e, and f.

Comment: that's invalid for Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I'm not too familiar with PostgresSQL and had already posted before they indicated RDBMS. I updated with what I think is valid PostgresSQL. Idea is still the same though.